# How to install a new keyboard layout which is not present in the iPhone using ios 6?

Tags: ios6

I am using iPhone 3gs(unlocked i mean apple genuine jail broken device). Its having inbuilt keyboard languages like "Hindi" "Chinese-Simplified" etc for adding a new keyboard.
How to install a new keyboard in the iPhone(through iTunes or anything) which is not present in the list.

For example: My local language is "Telugu". I want the Telugu keyboard to be installed into my device. Will it be possibe? (Remember one thing, I don't need any apps for my local language I need a software keyboard layout file)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike keyboards on Android, this is not possible on iOS.

Comment: May I know in what format(i.e extension) the keyboard layout files will be.. in the inbuilt os ?   (Eg: English.lproj, or Chinese.ipa)